# How do I calculate the most probable orbital an electron is in?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, measurement-problem, orbitals

If I saw a snapshot in time of an electron near a proton (Hydrogen), then the electron can be in any orbital as long as it doesn't lie on a node of the wave function. So how would I determine which orbital it is most likely occupying?

EDIT: To phrase this a different way, how can I find out which wave function has the highest probability at a location. According to this graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNelW.gif for any r I chose there is one orbital (except where they intersect where there are two) which has the highest probability value. This is what I mean. I guess as an added question, what is this quality that I seem to mistakenly be describing?

Comment: Your question is a bit naive, since "snapshot" is not physically meaningful, and further you haven't defined what knowledge you obtained in that snapshot.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to get a snapshot of an electron?

Answer (score 2):

Quantum mechanics tells us the probability for an electron in a certain orbital to be in a certain position or momentum state. Inverting this to find the probability for the electron to be in a certain orbital given its position or momentum state requires some *a priori* idea of what orbitals are the most probable. This is stated succinctly by Bayes' theorem:

$$
P(n,k,m \mid \vec x) \propto P(\vec x \mid n,k,m) P(n,k,m)
$$

The coefficient in this proportionality is fixed by requiring the norm of the probability to be unity. Without some good model for these *a priori* probabilities, the problem is un-answerable.

Luckily, a good model for these might be taken from thermodynamics. If the atom is in a bath of temperature $T$, the *a priori* probability to be in the state $\mid n,k,m \rangle$ is

$$
P(n,k,m) \propto \exp \left( - \frac{E(n,k,m)}{k_B T}\right)
$$
Again, the coefficient in this proportionality is fixed by requiring the norm of the probability to be unity. Of course, this is very simplified and ignores the kinetic and vibrational states available to atoms and molecules, which could complicate matters.

Edit: John Rennie's answer made be realize that the position $\vec x$ must be specified with some resolution $d^3 x$, otherwise the probabilities $P(\vec x \mid n,k,m) = \langle \vec x \mid n, k, m \rangle d^3 x$ are strictly 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have confused two separate things.

By *orbital* we normally mean the distinct atomic orbitals like $1s$, $2s$, $2p$, etc. These actually only exist for hydrogen atoms (and single electron ions) so let's just consider hydrogen for now. In practice if we do an experiment with a sample of hydrogen its energy is well characterised and under normal conditions the atoms will be in their ground state. That means we know the electron is in the $1s$ orbital.

If there is some energy input of a few eV or more, e.g. if you're heating the hydrogen, then there will be a chance that electrons will be excited to higher orbitals. In this case, as jwimberley says in his answer, the probability of state occupation will be given by a Boltzmann distribution.

But what I'm guessing you mean is where actually is the electron? That is, if we took a photograph as you suggest where would we see the little dot?

The answer is that the question doesn't make sense because the electron doesn't have a position. It is a delocalised object, not a tiny ball, and you can't ask what its position is because it has no position. However what you could ask is if I fired a high energy particle at different points in the atom what would be the probability of it hitting the electron? This does make sense, because even for a delocalised object the interaction with another object can be localised to an approximate point. In that case the probability of hitting the electon at a point would simply be proportional to $\Psi^*(\vec{r})\Psi(\vec{r})$, where $\Psi(\vec{r})$ is the value of the wavefunction at the point $\vec{r}$.

Response to comment:

Just to get the conclusion from the comments into the answer, The quantity $\psi^*\psi dV$ gives the probability of finding the electron in the volume element $dV$. So for any given volume element the relative values of $\psi^*\psi dV$ for all the different values will give you the relative probabilities that an electron found in that volume element is in the different orbitals.

However this applies only if you can assume that all electron energies are equally likely i.e. there are no other factors that would make some energies more probable than others. In practice it doesn't seem likely this would be the case for any experiment I can think of.

Comment: I'm considering this picture specifically: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UNelW.gif Now imagine the electron is placed on the r-axis below where the 2p orbital's probability derivative is 0. Since the 1s and 2s as well as all the other probabilities' have smaller heights at that same point, then I would say the electron is most likely in a 2p orbital. Perhaps my reasoning is wrong here on some level, but I would like to know why since this seems like a completely solvable problem from this perspective.

Comment: @Kainui: the electron distribution is a statistical one i.e. it gives the probability of finding the electron in a volume element $dV$. If you do a single experiment this tells you nothing about which orbital the electron is in. You'd have to do many such measurements. Even finding an electron where (for example) $\psi_{2s} = 0$ doesn't prove the electron isn't in a $2s$ state because you're always measuring a finite volume element and the wavefunction isn't zero everywhere in any finite volume element.

Comment: Though I guess if you calculate $\psi^*\psi dV$ for all the different orbitals this would give you the relative probabilities that the electron is in the different orbitals. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm not trying to prove with exactitude that the electron is anywhere. I'm just saying that relative to other orbitals, each one has a higher probability in different locations. So I'm trying to find which orbital has the largest probability for that location relative to all other orbitals.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want haha.